# Reading a File in Java in a Unix Server

Tags: java, input

I have the following lines of code that reads a TXT file (most of the time generated in Windows so it's ISO format) and it has the character **Ñ**. When I try to upload the file using Java on my workstation which is a Windows Machine, it is displayed properly and saved in the database properly. However, when I run the application on my app server which is Unix, the character Ñ is not displayed properly and turns into a symbol.

Here is the java code:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fu.getInputStream()));
String input;
try {
    while((input = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if(!input.equals("")) {
            items.add(input);
        }
    }
} finally {
    br.close();
}
```

Comment: Parse the file before uploading it in DB and remove the Ñ character from it and then upload it in DB . That will solve your problem .

Comment: @TheDarkKnight In the same way that using a flamethrower keeps your lawn from growing too much, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `InputStreamReader`'s constructor the charset parameter.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html

Comment: Do you mean pass it the the "iso-8859-1" charset?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Does that mean that the Unix Server uses the UTF encoding while reading the file? So by passing the "ISO-8859-1" encoding in the InputStreamReader constructor will make it use the ISO encoding?

Comment: @user3202905: Our Linux server uses UTF-8 as the default encoding. Probably yours is doing the same.

Comment: Thank you. Will try it as soon as I have access to our server.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following syntax to read the file.

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("yourfile"),
                    StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: It is not stated though, `java.nio.file.Files` is not avalibale in java 1.6. For below java 1.7 he can use guava Files.